# Configure JAX-RS base URI programmatically per deployment

Tags: rest, jax-rs, cdi, resteasy

Im trying to use CDI extensions to discover JAX-RS resources at runtime and automatically publish them under different base URIs in a Java SE environment. Applications should not need to extend `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` themselves if possible.

I have read RestEasy documentation and javadoc but failed to find any obvious way to modify the `@ApplicationPath` at runtime.

One idea that im exploring is to try generate `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` and set the `@ApplicationPath` base URI programmatically, maybe by using an AnnotatedType CDI extension, and publish that as a * org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment`.

Are there other/better ways to do this?

EDIT:

Trying CDI extension event `ProcessAnnotatedType` to change `@javax.ws.rs.Path` of JAX-RS resources.

```
<X> void process(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<X> pat) {
  if (!pat.getAnnotatedType().isAnnotationPresent(javax.ws.rs.Path.class)) {
    return;
  }
  final AnnotatedType<X> org = pat.getAnnotatedType();
  AnnotatedType<X> wrapped = new AnnotatedType<X>() {
    @Override
    public <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(final Class<T> annotation) {
    if (javax.ws.rs.Path.class.equals(annotation)) {
      class PathLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<javax.ws.rs.Path> implements javax.ws.rs.Path {
        @Override
        public String value() {
          return "change_me/" + (javax.ws.rs.Path) org.getAnnotation(annotation);
        }
      }
      return (T) new PathLiteral();
    } else {
      return org.getAnnotation(annotation);
    }
  }
  pat.setAnnotatedType(wrapped);
}
```

... then after bootstrap, constructing the bean using `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager` was expecting the following code to print "change_me/...."

```
Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(jaxrsClass);
for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {
  CreationalContext cc = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
  Object jaxrs = bean.create(cc);
  Path p = jaxrs.getClass().getAnnotation(Path.class);
  System.out.println(p.value());
}
```

... but this does not work. `javax.ws.rs.Path` is unchanged for JAX-RS resource 'jaxrsClass'.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this can be done in a reliable way. It probably all comes down to which happens first: the CDI bootstrap or JAX-RS, of course in the future or in other application servers it could all be done in parallel.

It's certainly a cool idea though. What have they said on the RestEasy forums?

Comment: I think im almost there, already managed to deploy jaxrs endpoints using this approach. But yes, im not sure if im hacking around jaxrs bootstrap here. I have posted a question on the resteasy user mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

We are already using such an approach.

We are using the feature to use Subresource locators and take the power of guice.

At the startup we are scanning the classpath for all resources annotated with @Path. After that we are extracting the path and binding the resources with the help of Names/@Named. So the resources can later be injected with the help of the name.

```
bind(..).annotatedWith(Names.named("path")).to(..)
```

The next step is that you need a resource with a subresource locator.

```
@Path("{name}")
public Object find(@PathParam("name") name){
    return injector.getInstance(..);
}
```

You could use this approach to bind them at runtime and also to change the original annotated path.

Comment: Very interesting! Im not familiar with Guice terminology. Does this put non-standard requirements on JAX-RS resources? Do you have a brief example of the JAX-RS resource?

Comment: You don't have to change your resources. I'll create a little project and post it here, so you can have a look how it is working.